# Spring: How to return all objects with joined references of an entity by default with CrudRepository

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have a product  table

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Product extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="optimized-sequence",sequenceName = "seq_product")
    private Integer id;
    private String sku;
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    *** 
    ***
    ***   

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts;

}
```

And a CrudRepository

```
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Integer> {

    Product findFirstBydescription(@Param("description")String description);

}
```

when i call the endpoint /products **by default**  I get a list of all products like this

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "products" : [ {
      "createdAt" : "2019-11-15T08:56:23.393+0000",
      "updatedAt" : "2019-11-15T08:56:23.393+0000",
      "id" : 802,
      "sku" : null,
      "name" : " product 1",
      "description" : "description one",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/802"
        },
        "product" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/802{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "manufacturer" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/802/manufacturer"
        },
        "orderProducts" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/802/orderProducts"
        },
        "category" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/802/category"
        }
      }
    }, .......
```

How can I get, calling the default endpoint /products, inside the json object product the related objects too (Catefory, Manufacturer...)?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

If am I understand you correctly, you should use **FetchType.EAGER**  strategy inside the @ManyToOne or @OneToOne annotations for fetching all related data from the database.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
private Category category;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
private Manufacturer manufacturer;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts;
```

Comment: `Spring-jpa creates the query using the entity manager, and Hibernate will ignore the fetch mode if the query was built by the entity manager.` @oguzhan00

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rewrite your query using [FETCH JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-in-hibernate):

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN FETCH p.category JOIN FETCH p.manufacturer JOIN FETCH p.orderProducts WHERE p.description = :description")
Product findFirstByDescription(@Param("description") String description);
```

It will fetch Product's associations eagerly.

Note that in this case you should make your associations lazily fetched (i.e set `fetch` parameter of association annotations to `EAGER`).

Comment: Sorry but is not that query. I want to get all related objecs in the default endponint /products that CrudRepository exposes by default

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible with Spring Data Rest**

It's not very clear in your question, but from what I see, I assume you use `Spring Data Rest` to expose your data.

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514131/spring-hateoas-versus-spring-data-rest)

> `Spring Data REST` uses `Spring HATEOAS` to automatically expose
>   resources for entities managed by Spring Data repositories and
>   leverages hypermedia aspects to do pagination, link entities etc.

The thing is, one of the main concepts behind HATEOAS is the [discovery mechanism](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235872/what-does-hateoas-offer-for-discoverability-and-decoupling-besides-ability-to-ch). It means that with an HATEOAS API, you won't have the possibility to make a "Lazy exposition" of your resources, it's against the philosophy of HATEOAS.

That's why I think if you really want related objects, you should avoid `Spring Data Rest`, it won't fit your needs.

Instead, you can make your own controllers. You will lose the facility that `Spring Data Rest` provides, with the *CRUD* operations already implemented for each entity. But you will have more flexibility with your data, and will be able to expose data with entities related in your JSON response.